# How can I send a message to a specific process by process id rather than by window handle?

Tags: c#, .net, sendmessage, inter-process-communicat

To work around the limitations of GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent, I have to create an intermediate "middle-man" process to handle launching some console applications.  The process's main purpose is to call GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent on itself, causing itself and all child process to close cleanly in response to a ctrl+break signal (rather than using Process.Kill).  This need arises from the fact that GenerateConsoelCtrlEvent basically has no effect unless the process group id is zero, which means it is only ever effective on the calling process group itself.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2431295/88409

So anyway... I've created this intermediate process, which starts a thread that calls Application.Run on a form which processes specific user-defined messages.

My problem is... how do send messages to this process to control it?

I have the Process object and its process id, but that's all.  Process.MainWindowHandle is zero.

So I need a way to send a message to a specific process or broadcast the message to all windows in a specific process.

FindWindow is not an option, because it tries to identify a window by name and class on any process, which is unreliable.  I want to send a message to a specific process with no ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send nor post a message to a process, but you can post a message to a thread. Of course, that thread must have started a message loop to process it.

Comment: So the primary target of a message is a thread, and it is optional for such a thread message to target a specific window.  This is reflected by the Win32 methods PostThreadMessage and PostMessage, whose signatures are similar, except that the first parameter of one is a thread id, while the other is a window handle.  Since the primary target is a thread message queue, the PostMessage function must first identify the thread that owns the window handle, and post the message to that thread's message queue through some internal function that accepts both a thread id and window handle.

Comment: Since "SendMessage" bypasses the message queue and routes the message directly to a window procedure, it may be more complete to say you can "post" a message to a thread, but you cannot "send" a message to a thread.  That is why there is no such thing as "*Send*ThreadMessage".  Incidentally, SendMessage would have the side effect of bypassing a TranslateMessage call as well, since that's called in the message loop.  If you bypass the loop by calling SendMessage, you'd also bypass the TranslateMessage call.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, but I'm also going to leave my own answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16157666/88409) with code that can be used to target a message *conceptually* at a process, without specifying a thread or window, such that a target thread or window is selected automatically through enumeration.  The purpose of these methods is to make it easier to spawn a process and send control messages to it, without the extra step of identifying a specific thread or window handle, which can be done automatically.

Answer (score 10):

There are 3 scenarios in which a message could be *thought of* as being sent or posted to a process:

1. I can "send" or "post" a [window] message to a specific process by sending it to the first enumerated window in that process
2. I can "post" a [thread] message to a specific process by posting it to the first enumerated thread in the process.
3. I can "post" a [thread] message to a specific process by posting it to the thread that owns the first enumerated window of that process.

Approach 1 may be too specific, since it targets a specific but arbitrary window.
Approach 2 may be not specific enough, since the first enumerated thread is arbitrary and may not have a message loop.
Approach 3 is a hybrid approach that first identifies a window, but then posts a thread message to that window's thread, so it is not targetted at a specific window (i.e. it's a "thread message") but it is targetted at a thread that is likely to have a message loop since the thread owns at least one window.

The following is an implementation that supports all three approaches and both methods "send" and "post".  Approach 1 is encompassed by the methods SendMessage and PostMessage below.  Approach 2 and 3 are encompassed by the method PostThreadMessage below, depending on whether you set the optional parameter `ensureTargetThreadHasWindow` (true = approach 3, false = approach 2).

```
public static class ProcessExtensions
{
    private static class Win32
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool PostThreadMessage(uint threadId, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate (IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(uint dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
    }

    //Sends a message to the first enumerated window in the first enumerated thread with at least one window, and returns the handle of that window through the hwnd output parameter if such a window was enumerated.  If a window was enumerated, the return value is the return value of the SendMessage call, otherwise the return value is zero.
    public static IntPtr SendMessage( this Process p, out IntPtr hwnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam )
    {
        hwnd = p.WindowHandles().FirstOrDefault();
        if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            return Win32.SendMessage( hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
        else
            return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    //Posts a message to the first enumerated window in the first enumerated thread with at least one window, and returns the handle of that window through the hwnd output parameter if such a window was enumerated.  If a window was enumerated, the return value is the return value of the PostMessage call, otherwise the return value is false.
    public static bool PostMessage( this Process p, out IntPtr hwnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam )
    {
        hwnd = p.WindowHandles().FirstOrDefault();
        if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            return Win32.PostMessage( hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
        else
            return false;
    }

    //Posts a thread message to the first enumerated thread (when ensureTargetThreadHasWindow is false), or posts a thread message to the first enumerated thread with a window, unless no windows are found in which case the call fails.  If an appropriate thread was found, the return value is the return value of PostThreadMessage call, otherwise the return value is false.
    public static bool PostThreadMessage( this Process p, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, bool ensureTargetThreadHasWindow = true )
    {
        uint targetThreadId = 0;
        if (ensureTargetThreadHasWindow)
        {
            IntPtr hwnd = p.WindowHandles().FirstOrDefault();
            uint processId = 0;
            if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
                targetThreadId = Win32.GetWindowThreadProcessId( hwnd, out processId );
        }
        else
        {
            targetThreadId = (uint)p.Threads[0].Id;
        }
        if (targetThreadId != 0)
            return Win32.PostThreadMessage( targetThreadId, msg, wParam, lParam );
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IntPtr> WindowHandles( this Process process )
    {
        var handles = new List<IntPtr>();
        foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
            Win32.EnumThreadWindows( (uint)thread.Id, (hWnd, lParam) => { handles.Add(hWnd); return true; }, IntPtr.Zero );
        return handles;
    }
}
```

To use this extension method on a Process object:

```
Process process = Process.Start( exePath, args );
IntPtr hwndMessageWasSentTo = IntPtr.Zero; //this will receive a non-zero value if SendMessage was called successfully
uint msg = 0xC000; //The message you want to send
IntPtr wParam = IntPtr.Zero; //The wParam value to pass to SendMessage
IntPtr lParam = IntPtr.Zero; //The lParam value to pass to SendMessage

IntPtr returnValue = process.SendMessage( out hwndMessageWasSentTo, msg, wParam, lParam );
if (hwndMessageWasSentTo != IntPtr.Zero)
   Console.WriteLine( "Message successfully sent to hwnd: " + hwndMessageWasSentTo.ToString() + " and return value was: " + returnValue.ToString() );
else
   Console.WriteLine( "No windows found in process.  SendMessage was not called." );
```

Comment: I see, you answered your own question.  :-)  The crux of the problem is actually communicating the intermediate process's main thread ID to the sender.  Once you have achieved that, `PostThreadMessage()` is straightforward.

Comment: the process that i'm sending to has no window, only process id, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to scan the top level windows, and use [GetProcessHandleFromHWnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318087%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine whether a window is in your target process.

You can then send messages to that hwnd, and they should be received by your target process (if your target process has a message loop).

Comment: I would prefer to use Process.Threads (return ProcessThread[]), then call EnumThreadWindows on each thread to get the windows.  If were to instead call EnumWindows, it would return windows from many processes, so I'd have to filter the windows by calling GetProcessHandleFromHWnd on each handle.  Using GetWindowThreadProcessId as suggested by Medinoc would also require me to filter the windows by checking whether Process.Threads collection for the target thread contains a thread with the window's owner thread id.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a very similar question (with sample code) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61603909/420400).
The quick answer is `PostThreadMessage()`.