# What does com.mathworks.mde.cmdwin.CmdWin means in MATLAB? Is there any documentation regarding this?

Tags: java, matlab

```
function interrupt

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent
import java.lang.reflection.*

base = com.mathworks.mde.cmdwin.CmdWin.getInstance();
hCmd = base.getComponent(0).getViewport().getView();
cmdwin = handle(hCmd,'CallbackProperties');

argSig = javaArray('java.lang.Class',1);
argSig(1) = java.lang.Class.forName('java.awt.event.KeyEvent');

msTime = (8.64e7 * (now - datenum('1970', 'yyyy')));
args = javaArray('java.lang.Object',1);
args(1) = KeyEvent(cmdwin,KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,msTime,...
    KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK,KeyEvent.VK_C,KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED);

method = cmdwin.getClass().getDeclaredMethod('processKeyEvent',argSig);
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(cmdwin,args);
```

The above code was pasted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21930656/1255289). I just need to understand or find API/Documentation about this line:

```
com.mathworks.mde.cmdwin.CmdWin.getInstance();
```

I saw similar stuff all over the internet. What is it and where can I find any source?

Comment: It gets the Java handle to MATLAB's command window. MATLAB's underlying Java is not documented.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unsupported and undocumented API to access the command window. More examples of its use can be found at [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/changing-matlab-command-window-colors). You're accessing directly the Java components that MATLAB is built with, so it's best not to rely on these things to be stable or long-lived.

Comment: Thanks, for the info. I am trying to find a way to automatically execute/code Ctrl+C. I looked at everything and I am out of luck. So I decided to look into Java stuff. It works, but I want to do something that I understand.Can you suggest something?

Comment: @SimonMatt Have you looked into the `java.awt.Robot` class? A similar example can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933270/programmatically-press-an-enter-key-after-starting-exe-file-in-matlab - Modify for your own purposes.

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem using Robot. However, solution from @MattB works. But that solution is very hard to understand.