Matlab: Stop execution of one line but continue program execution
In Matlab, I need to perform a calculation.  There are two ways I can do this calculation, but I don't know a priori which one will be easier.  One way will take the computer a millisecond to finish, and the other will take minutes.  So I need a way to ask Matlab how long it's been stuck on one line of code.  Something like this:
start timer
run this line of code
if 0.1 second has passed
  stop and run this line of code
end

Is this possible?
Note that this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925137/how-can-i-abort-program-execution-in-matlab is not relevant because I don't want to actually stop the program.

I don't think you can do that. I think you need to rewrite the first bit of code to be aware of how long it's running, and have it return an error value (or error out) if it's taking too long. I assume that bit of code has a loop, in the loop you can check how long it's been running and just error if it's too long. The calling code can try/catch and run the second bit of code in the catch part.

Why can't you save the state, do the method that takes 1ms and if it doesn't get the right answer then and only then use the slower method. Otherwise you have to add something in the iterative code loop to give up after N seconds of wall clock time. IOW "this line of code" needs to have a way of returning a timeout error to your program.

Well the problem is I don't know which one will take a short time vs. a long time. But I think what you both said is the way to go.  Unless...I can use multiprocessing to both at once and stop both after 2ms.

You could take advantage of some thread/process management routines. Something along the lines of:
% Create a thread pool
pool = parpool('Threads');


% Submit the tasks to the thread pool
future1 = parfeval(pool, @countToN, 0, 10);
future2 = parfeval(pool, @countToN, 0, 1000);

% Periodically check if any of the threads have finished
while ~strcmp(future1.State,'finished') && ~strcmp(future2.State,'finished')
    pause(0.1); % Check every 100ms
    disp("checking stats")
    if strcmp(future1.State,'finished')
        fprintf('Task 1 finished, cancelling Task 2.\n');
        future2.cancel();
    elseif strcmp(future2.State,'finished')
        fprintf('Task 2 finished, cancelling Task 1.\n');
        future1.cancel();
    end
end

% Wait for both tasks to finish (in case they were cancelled)
wait([future1, future2]);

% Clean up the thread pool
delete(pool);

function countToN(n)
for i = 1:n
    fprintf('Counting to %d: %d\n', n, i);
    pause(0.1); % 10ms delay
end
end


How interesting.  I've never done multithreading before, so I'll have to look into this.  Thanks a bunch.
