# Running cleanup code on script abort

Tags: matlab

I'm sure this has been asked before but I just cant find it.

What I want to do is have some code run when I abort(CTRL+C) a script while it's running, for example, if I open a file I'd like the close command to run even if I abort or there's an error.

Something like try\finally in other languages, only there's no error on abort so try\catch will not work here.

Thanks.

Comment: See the Java implementation.
[Matlab: implementing what CTRL+C does, but in the code][1].

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033078/matlab-implementing-what-ctrlc-does-but-in-the-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`onCleanup`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html), which is intended for exactly this purpose.

`onCleanup` creates an object that, when it goes out of scope (and therefore gets deleted), executes some code. So, for example,

```
c1 = onCleanup(@() disp('goodbye'))
```

creates an object `c1`. When `c1` goes out of scope, it is deleted, and `goodbye` is displayed. Similarly

```
c2 = onCleanup(@() fclose(fid))
```

creates an object that, when deleted, closes the file with ID `fid`.

You'll need to make a change to your coding style to take advantage of `onCleanup` - specifically, you'll need to implement things as functions rather than scripts. Scripts use the base workspace, so when the finish, any cleanup objects you've created remain in the base workspace without going out of scope and being deleted, so their code never executes.

By contrast, functions have their own workspace, which is cleared when they finish, automatically deleting any cleanup objects. Importantly for your question, this workspace is cleared not only when the function finishes normally, but also if it finishes with an error, and even if it finishes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

It's usually simple to modify a script to a function: if the script is called `mytest.m`, just put `function mytest` at the top of the script. There are situations where this won't work (e.g. if your script depends on other variables being available in the base workspace), but those are situations that it's not a good idea to be in anyway.

As an example, run the following program:

```
function mytest

c = onCleanup(@() disp('goodbye'));

for i = 1:1000000
    disp(i)
end
```

During execution, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. You should see that `goodbye` is displayed after the last number.

Comment: On my Matlab 2014b this doesn't work. Hitting ctrl-c stops the loop without displaying `goodbye`.

Comment: @FrankMeulenaar I don't have 14b available right now, but I've just tested it on 14a and 16a, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the CTRL-C shortcut.

See [Actions for Which You Cannot Customize Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/keyboard-shortcuts.html#br5rvdi) in the matlab doc.