# How would I terminate a program in MatLab from the Command Window without using Ctrl-C?

Tags: matlab, break

I am trying to find a way to setup my program to terminate when I enter a specific command into the Command Window. I'm running an indefinite loop on purpose in order to make a basic autopilot style program for an arduino train set. I just need a way to end the program.

Comment: autohotkey ? not sure what u mean

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033078/matlab-implementing-what-ctrlc-does-but-in-the-code