# How do I mimic a button click in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

How do I mimic a button click in matlab?

Simply excecuting the callback function doesn't work since within its callback it uses the [gcbo](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcbo.html) command and I cannot alter the excecuting function. I furthermore would not like to shadow gcbo for obvious reasons.

In case it matters I look for a solution which works on matlab R2012a.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try calling the **java.awt.Robot** class, for example.

```
robot = java.awt.Robot;
pause(2) % wait some time
robot.keyPress (java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); % press "enter" key
robot.keyRelease (java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); %  release "enter" key
```

read more about GUI automation using a Robot [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/gui-automation-robot)...

I'm not sure this will work on Matlab R2012a, but it does on later versions.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick, with mousePress / mouseRelease its possible. A shame that there is no event to notify or similar.

Comment: Always liked this trick. +1  @magu_ see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27933690/2778484) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10033078/2778484) for some interesting examples.

Comment: please note that this will also be executed outside the matlab environment

Answer (score 1):

`gcbo` only contain the button handle. If you have (or can retrieve/find) the button handle, just call the function callback with the button handle as first argument and an empty variable as the second argument.

something looking like that:

```
button_callback( buttonHandle , [] ) ;
```

The callback will not make any difference between `gcbo` or the button handle and will function exactly the same.

---

If you do not have the button handle in the first place, you can try to find it with [`findobj`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html):

```
buttonHandle  = findobj(gcf,'Style','PushButton','String','The Button Text')
```

Depending on how the GUI was built/defined, then handle visibility may not be immediately apparent, in which case you can search deeper with [`findall`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findall.html):

```
buttonHandle   = findall(gcf,'Style','PushButton','String','The Button Text')
```

or may be the handle was nicely saved in the guidata structure:

```
handles = guidata(gcf) ;
```

and search the structure for what may be your button handle.

**Note:** in the last 3 examples above, make sure the GUI figure which contains the button has the focus before you call `gcf`, or better yet, replace `gcf` by the actual figure handle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do have the handle of the button, the problem is that the callback function itself calls gbco. Sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: @magu_, Actually you did make it clear, it's me who got confused on the ways to override the callback input. It would help if you could post a bit of the code which uses `gcbo`, so we can see if there are ways around your problem.

Comment: That's a nice offer but the problem is as follows: The code is written/maintained by another person but I have to use it. Unfortunately the only interface I have for it is the gui with its buttons without actually changing the code.