# How can I stop a script in MATLAB when it takes longer than a specified number of seconds using the timer object?

Tags: matlab

I run a matlab script multiple times per day and a lot of times it takes too long to execute. What I want to do is set off a timer that keeps track of how long the script has been running for and stops the script when it takes longer than a specified number of seconds

I have tested this principle on a simple script:

```
waittime = 5;
t = timer('TimerFcn','error(''Process ended because it took too long'')',waittime); 
start(t)
pause(10);
```

What I would expect to happen is that this function waits for 5 seconds and afterwards it will execute the stop function which is the `error('Process ended because it took too long')` command.

When running this, the stop command will execute, however it does not stop the main script from running.

In my command window I see

```
Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-20' 
Process ended because it took too long
```

Afterwards the script is not stopped, and keeps running for the full 10 seconds

I don't want this error to be cast over the `TimerFcn` function, I want this error to be cast over the running script such that it stops running.

Is there any way I can control the script/function over which the error is cast?

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible.... If it is an iterative method, then you could always check after each iteration....

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the the script and can periodically check for the time inside the script, you can do something like this

```
waittime = 3;
endt=true;
t = timer('TimerFcn','endt=false; disp(''Timer!'')','StartDelay',waittime); 
start(t);

i=1;
while endt==true
    a=exp(i);
    i=i+1;
    pause(0.1);
end
```

If you do not have any bits that are periodic or do not have access to the script, I think your best bet is described here

[Matlab: implementing what CTRL+C does, but in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033078/matlab-implementing-what-ctrlc-does-but-in-the-code)

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ander Biguri that I don't think this is possible. What you can do is make the TimerFcn do something that causes an error somehwere else.

```
waittime = 5;
d=1;go=1;
t = timer('TimerFcn','clear d','StartDelay',waittime); 
start(t)
while go
    pause(0.1)
    1/d;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Given [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10033078/52738), you'll probably have to resort to some Java tricks to do this, since throwing an error message doesn't interrupt the [`pause`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html) statement. However, if the script you're running can periodically break computation and perform checks on the state, you can incorporate a [timer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) as follows:

```
% Initialization:
maxRunTime = 5;
tObj = timer('TimerFcn', @(~, ~) disp('Time''s up!'), 'StartDelay', maxRunTime);

% Script:
start(tObj);
while strcmp(get(tObj, 'Running'), 'on')
  % Do some computations
end
delete(tObj);
```

This checks the running state of the timer to determine if the loop continues, so the timer function doesn't have to modify any variables or throw any errors.