# Trying to send data from WPF application to Web Page on any Web Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, vb6, pinvoke

A possible duplicate: [Directly sending keystrokes to another process via hooking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407769/directly-sending-keystrokes-to-another-process-via-hooking)

I would like to apologize if the tone in my question is a bit bad. I am stuck right know. 
Okay, I am working to make a program that would transfer data from a WPF application to  both a VB 6 application and a web page. Depending on the configuration it will call a procedure to post data. I already finished the VB 6 side but having a big issue with the web page since:

- The procedure MUST work on all known browsers.
- I am not allowed to send the data as a web request.
- I don't have control for the web site to be used.
- I also am not allowed to use any third party software

I already tried the following:

- Sendmessage with keyup and keydown for tab and character keys
- Sendmessage with postmessage for the string to be sent
- Postmessage version of the above
- MSHTML for sending data as HTMLdocument
- SendKeys (though not yet explored it heavily)

Here is the code for the sendmessage (closest to all of my tries)

```
   IntPtr window = User32_Methods.FindWindow(null, "Test Site");
        if(window!=IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("asdasd");
            User32_Methods.SendMessage(window, Send_Message_Constants.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            User32_Methods.SendMessage(window, Send_Message_Constants.WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            for (int count = 0; count < 15;count++)
            {
                User32_Methods.PostMessage(window, Send_Message_Constants.WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr) Send_Message_Constants.VK_TAB, IntPtr.Zero);
                User32_Methods.PostMessage(window, Send_Message_Constants.WM_KEYUP, (IntPtr)Send_Message_Constants.VK_TAB, IntPtr.Zero);
                foreach(char a in "adasdasdasd")
                {
                    User32_Methods.PostMessage(window, Send_Message_Constants.WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)Send_Message_Constants.VK_A, IntPtr.Zero);
                    User32_Methods.PostMessage(window, Send_Message_Constants.WM_KEYUP, (IntPtr)Send_Message_Constants.VK_A, IntPtr.Zero);
                }
            }
        }
```

I would like to ask you guys at stack since you solved most of the questions that I am having an issue here.

Comment: Do you have a list of all known browsers?

Comment: IE, Firefox, Chrome, Rockmelt and Safari. The Chrome and Firefox are preferred.

Comment: I can think of a few more. Opera for a start. There are others. This info needs to be in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this might not be the way to go, however I am seeing that you are gonna try to use send keys, so maybe you can add some .js fo you own, with your logic and just execute it. Since send keys will be like a way to input the data to the forms/click a button/ or something else, the js routine might help you....