# Is there a way to "Listen" for commands in a running exe?

Tags: vb6

I have built an app that constantly reads a MySQL database to check if there have been changes on a table.
This generates a heavy load on the small MySQL server.

The app is used across 3 different locations by +300 people.

I wonder if there is a way to send a "command" to the running app to do a function?

I don't want to use Winsock for this one, and I cannot find a yes or no answer on Google.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an update trigger on your table to start a shell to run python 3 or java script. It could then be used to update a vb app running on the server designed to distribute the information when it is received. I know it sounds like allot, but there is no direct method. I would experiment with crating the trigger and java script and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could find your application's process and send keys to it, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407769/directly-sending-keystrokes-to-another-process-via-hooking/).

In your application you can handle the key and check for changes in the MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Since you check a table in a mysql database, you should create a table in which you write a record that could be read by the app and understood as a command. The structure of the table should permit to specify some rules like execute it on a specific location only or all of them, at what time it must be played now or in xx minutes or whatever, the parameters to use during execution, etc...

So when you want your app to execute something, you just add a record to the table, with needed parameters.