# How to get GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent to work with cmd.exe

Tags: windows, winapi, cmd, console-application, windows-console

I'm trying to get `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` to work. This is the minimal example I've come up with:

```
#include <Windows.h>

static BOOL WINAPI handler(DWORD CtrlType)
{
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(&handler, TRUE))
    {
        throw 1;
    }

    STARTUPINFO si = {0};
    DWORD dwStartupFlags = 0;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    if (!CreateProcess(
        NULL,
        "cmd.exe",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        dwStartupFlags,
        NULL, // environ
        NULL, // cwd
        &si,
        &pi))
    {
        throw 1;
    }
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

    DWORD exitCode;
    while(true)
    {
        switch (WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 1000 * 10))
        {
          case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0);
            //WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
            break;

          case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitCode);
            return exitCode;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So I start it up, type in something (no newline), and wait 10 seconds. The debugger shows the Ctrl-C event. The console shows that the Ctrl-C had no effect.

I tracked down the issue to this: the main cmd.exe thread calls `ReadConsoleW`. Under the test program with `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`, this does not return. Pressing Ctrl-C does make it return, with `*lpNumberOfCharsRead==0`.

`GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` starts a new thread using `kernel32!CtrlRoutine`. If, using the debugger, you freeze this thread, cmd.exe still behaves as if Ctrl-C was pressed. In fact, you can trick cmd.exe into believing that there is was a Ctrl-C pressed if you set `*lpNumberOfCharsRead==NULL` when `ReadConsoleW` returns after a return keypress.

`cmd.exe` is not unique in the behavior: Python.exe's read returns immediately upon Ctrl-C, but not upon `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`. Python.exe uses `ReadFile`. (Python.exe notices the KeyboardInterrupt after you press enter.)

So the question is: why does `ReadConsoleW` return immediately when you press Ctrl-C, but not when `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` is called? As far as I can tell, on Windows 7, pressing Ctrl-C sends messages that are read by `conhost.exe` which communicates with `csrss.exe`, which calls `NtCreateThreadEx` with `kernel32!CtrlRoutine`. I do not see that it does anything else when you press Ctrl-C. But what is causing `ReadConsoleW` to return?

Comment: The SetConsoleMode() winapi function, ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT option flag is relevant. It allows a program to specify whether it wants to see Ctrl+C itself or leave it up to the system to handle it.

This flag is definitely off for cmd.exe.  Since pressing Ctrl+C doesn't terminate it.

Comment: try starting something besides cmd.exe then I guess?  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows

Comment: In the test program, if you swap `cmd.exe` with `Python.exe`, it behaves similarly: the `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` has no immediate effect, but `Python.exe`notices the Ctrl+C after you press enter. I don't think `cmd.exe` is unique here.