# Send WM_CLOSE message to a process with no window

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Starting a process -

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("G:\\SampleWinApp.exe");            
 psi.UseShellExecute = false;
 psi.CreateNoWindow = true;            
 Process prcs = Process.Start(psi);
```

Send [WM_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using PostMessage

```
const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;

public void SendCloseSignal(Process proc)
{
    uint uiPid = (uint) proc.Id;
    bool bResult = EnumWindows(new WNDENUMPROC(EnumWindowsProc), uiPid);
    if (!bResult && Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == 0) {
        object objWnd = processWnd[uiPid];
        if (objWnd != null) {
            IntPtr ptrWnd = (IntPtr) objWnd;
            PostMessage(ptrWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
    }

    foreach (ProcessThread thread in proc.Threads) {
        PostThreadMessage((uint) thread.Id, WM_CLOSE, UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

}

private static bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hwnd, uint lParam)
{
    uint uiPid = 0;
    if (GetParent(hwnd) == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, ref uiPid);
        if (uiPid == lParam)
        {
            processWnd[uiPid] = hwnd;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Start exe with `CreateNoWindow = false`, WM_CLOSE message is send and application shuts down gracefully. 
With `CreateNoWindow = true`, WM_CLOSE message never reach the proess. Even PostThreadMessage does not seem to work. Is there any way to send WM_CLOSE message? I have search for a day to find a solution to this.. no luck.

**Edit:** A windows service is installed for every application. Starting/Stopping the service starts/stops the application. Currently we kill the application on service stop. As its a brute force kill, applications do not die gracefully. Some of the applications listen for [CTRL signals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Now, I just need some way to send WM_CLOSE message to these applications.

**Edit2:** If there is a window, WM_CLOSE triggers a [CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But when any process is started with CreateNoWindow = true, this never triggers.

Comment: Well, you can't post messages to a window handle that doesn't exist.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: sry, typo. Edited now.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: any workaround?

Comment: @AseemGautam You can Kill(brutal) it.

Comment: Workaround to do what? You've not stated any requirements. You just seem to ask about sending `WM_CLOSE`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: yea, that is exactly what is happening right now.

Comment: You can send WM_CLOSE to a process that has no window but it will never do anything because it has no message pump, no windowproc and no defwinproc. If you want alternative ways to shut things down, read on. If not, we're done here.

Comment: [PostThreadMessage to Console Application](http://simplesamples.info/Windows/PostThreadMessage.aspx)

Comment: I would change WM_CLOSE to WM_QUIT in PostThreadMessage() ===> const int WM_QUIT = 0x0012;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to send WM_CLOSE message?

`WM_CLOSE` is sent to a window. If there is no window in the process, then there is nothing to process the message. If you wish to close a process that has no window, then sending `WM_CLOSE` is not the solution.

It looks like you simply want to kill processes. And you are using `WM_CLOSE` messages to trigger `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` signals when the console processes have associated windows.

Since `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` is already a rather brutal way to kill a process, you could be perfectly well justified, in my view, to simply kill it. You already have a `Process` object. Simply kill it using `Process.Kill()`.

On the other hand, perhaps the question that you really wanted to ask was:

> How do I signal `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` in another process?

A related question can be found here: [Can I send a ctrl-C (SIGINT) to an application on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows) The best answer there in my view, not the accepted one, is that of Nemo1024. That answer links to his blog article: http://stanislavs.org/stopping-command-line-applications-programatically-with-ctrl-c-events-from-net/

As I understand it, that article should give you the information needed to solve your problem. It lists four scenarios. The first two involve `WM_CLOSE` as a means to trigger the close signal. The third is to kill the process. And the fourth is probably what you are looking for. Of course this fourth option is the most complex. To quote from the article:

> After finding a hint at the bottom of this thread, I finally bit the bullet and started the process without a window. When the time comes to stop a process, the parent attaches its console to the child, stops itself listening to Ctrl-C event and issues the event to the console, so that the attached child terminates. It then reinstates the Ctrl-C handler for itself and frees the console.

Comment: So if that's not the solution, what is?

Comment: @Gabe What is the problem?

Comment: David, Not to be very strict. You can understand from the question right OP is struggling "How to close a window....". You explained why it doesn't work, It will be better if you can say what are the options op have in hand. 1) Kill is a brutal option available.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Maybe. But I tend to believe in answering the question that was asked. I don't really want to speculate as to what the actual problem is. The asker didn't state the underlying problem. I don't feel terribly confident in trying to guess what it is.

Comment: I still don't really understand, and I don't know what `FireDaemon` is. You want to send `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` or `CTRL_C_EVENT` signals? If so I wonder why the question asks about `WM_CLOSE`.

Comment: Yes, some of the processes are command line programs. CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT would trigger a clean exit.

Comment: PostMessage(WM_CLOSE) triggers a CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, but does not work with processes with no window.

Comment: CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT might be brutal, but a console application can trap this event. I made a simple exe, I could debug this event and do some quick cleanup tasks.

Comment: It sounds to me as though the question you wanted to ask is, *how do I send a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` signal to another process?*