# Capture .Net Console Kill or Terminate

Tags: c#, events, process, console, ipc

So I have a hidden console application called Hidden.exe running.
Another application Call Killer.exe will find the process Hidden.exe or its PID, and Kills the process.

How do i programmatically capture a kill command or a terminate from Task Manager? A user can browse through the process list and 'End Task' on Hidden.exe and I want to be able to capture this event and do some cleanup before it exits.

How can i do this? I have searched around, and explored alternatives from
[.NET console application exit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119841/net-console-application-exit-event)
[Send WM_CLOSE message to a process with no window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197669/send-wm-close-message-to-a-process-with-no-window)
[Can I send a ctrl-C (SIGINT) to an application on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows)
etc....

But they all dont work or only work in some cases, my case is for a hidden console application and needs to somehow capture a Kill on it. None of the above solution seem to have a 'correct' solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such answer. A kill will always work and will fire no event. This is due to security concern to prevent virus and/or malware code.

I've since found another way.