# Closing an application properly: an Alternative to TerminateProcess

Tags: c++, winapi, process, ipc, termination

I'm facing an issue with **TerminateProcess()** function.
The application I'm currently writing a JobScheduler app that schedules and launches job at a specific time.
For this purpose, I'm using **CreateProcess()** to execute my JobLauncher.

The JobLauncher process then launches a console program (using createprocess ) which effectively executes the job executable, waits for its termination and monitors the duration, user and kernel times elapsed etc.

In order to kill the job from the JobScheduler I firstly started using TerminateProcess() but it does not allow me to close the executable itself properly. I mean i found no way to hook any termination event.

Until I find a better way than a brutal **TerminateProcess()**, I wrote an intermediate solution using the **GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent()** in the calling program.

In the job application that launches the target job executable, I installed a handler using **SetConsoleCtrlHandler()**.
And in the handler, I can terminate the process of the job and notifies my thirdparties properly.
This is the better solution I found for now.

> Is there a better way to programmaticaly and properly close a process ? 
>   Do you this solution is completly absurd ?
>   I'm not a "system-level" specialist developer though...

Z.

Comment: Send the `WM_CLOSE` message to that process?

Comment: What do you mean by "[`TerminateProcess`] does not allow me to close the executable itself properly"?  `TerminateProcess` is the most brutal way to terminate a process, it yanks the rug out -- no DLL detach notifications, no file buffers flushed, goodbye right now.  Any handles that process had open will be closed on its behalf (including to its own executable file).

Comment: @Adam: I mean that TerminateProcess simply "terminate" the process. Period. The "terminated" process is not notified beforehand.

Comment: @John: The joblauncher is a console application. I've no HWND handle and I do not wish to create one.

Comment: Raise an event in JobLauncher, which the console program has a thread blocked on `WaitForSingleObject` for?

Answer (score 0):

This well know Windows console problem and you can find some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows/1179124).

We used on internal console utility which has name "Kamikaze". It worked as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12899190/2224851) and for me it's a best solution cause there is no problem with porting between Windows versions and Windows architectures (x86, x64).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm happy to see that the solution I wrote is not that bad at all !