# After sending ctrl-c to a child proc., how do I re-attach handling to parent without ctrl-c being automatically handled (windows)?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, console

EDIT: Related post and possible .Net solution: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows) (I would like a non-.Net solution)

I have a need to shut-down a child process with a given process ID. My first attempt was to use this code:

```
bool shutDown(int const processID)
{
    // detach handler from 'this', parent process
    SetConsoldeCtrlHandler(NULL, TRUE);

    // send ctrl-c event to processID
    bool success = false;
    FreeConsole();
    AttachConsole(processID);
    success = GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0);

    while(waitUntilSomething()) {}

    return success;
}
```

Now this works fine, however, I would like to return console ctrl to the 'this' process so that if I want to, I can break out of the while loop. With this in mind, I tried this:

```
bool shutDown(int const processID)
{
    // detach handler from 'this' process
    SetConsoldeCtrlHandler(NULL, TRUE);

    // send ctrl-c event to processID
    bool success = false;
    FreeConsole();
    AttachConsole(processID);
    success = GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0);

    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, FALSE); // <--- I added this bit

    while(waitUntilSomething()) {}

    return success;
}
```

But this doesn't work, because the ctrl-c signal then falls through to the parent process and the while loop is never executed.

I also tried the following, using a custom handler to ignore ctrl-c events from 'this':

```
BOOL WINAPI handler(DWORD eventType)
{
    switch(eventType) {
        case CTRL_EVENT:
        case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
            return TRUE;
        default:
            return FALSE;
    }
}

bool shutDown(int const processID)
{
    // attach custom handler to i
    SetConsoldeCtrlHandler(handler, TRUE);

    // send ctrl-c event to processID
    bool success = false;
    FreeConsole();
    AttachConsole(processID);
    success = GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0);

    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(handler, FALSE);

    while(waitUntilSomething()) {}

    return success;
}
```

...but in a similar way to the second example, the ctrl-c then passes straight through to the parent process and the while loop is never executed, because of the second SetConsoleCtrlHandler(handler, FALSE); call.

Is there a way that I can return ctrl-c handling to the parent process after generating a ctrl-c event for a child process, without that event being automatically handled?

Thanks,

Ben.

Comment: IMO, `C` tag is not required here.

Comment: The windows api is a C api. But I will remove it.

Comment: Ctrl+C is a pretty rude way to terminate a console mode app.  It *could* implement a notification handler for it, that is not very common.  Which makes it indistinguishable for the much simpler way to do this, Process.Kill().

Comment: Well firstly, Process.Kill is part of the .Net api which I don't have access to. But more fundamentally is that Process.Kill *terminates the process* which doesn't allow that process to tidy itself up before gracefully closing. I need a graceful shutdown.