# Send SIGINT in Windows using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sigint

I try this code in Linux:

```
import os
import signal

for i in range(10000):
    print i
    if i==6666:
        os.kill(os.getpid(),signal.SIGINT)
```

it works well. But it doesn't work in Windows, because the attribute 'kill' is not present in os module for Windows

How can I send SIGINT to self program in Windows?

Comment: I don't know if SIGINT exists on Windows.  You might want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows

Comment: i don't want kill program.. i just want to send cntrl-c in self program..

Comment: @EricRenouf: Yeah, SIGINT is not a Windows thing at all. (*nix signals aren't actually a Windows thing, even; there are broadly similar mechanisms, but they don't map cleanly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from win32api import GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent
GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)
```