# sending CTRL-C to a process - but not to end it

Tags: c#, process

I am controlling a console process which has been started like this:

```
           AvrGdb = new Process();
        AvrGdb.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        AvrGdb.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        AvrGdb.StartInfo.FileName = "avr-gdb.exe";
        AvrGdb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        AvrGdb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        AvrGdb.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

I'm sending short command strings to the 'command line' and receiving data back. However one of the commands that needs to be sent is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This doesn't shut down the process, it sends it on to control a debugger in a separate microcontroller (the process is the 'avr-gdb' debugger for avr micros).

I have tried  both `StandardInput.Write('\x3')` and `StandardInput.Write(char.ConvertFromUtf32(3));` with no success (i.e. there is no reaction from the process I am writing to).

Many other topics on this subject exist but generally the questioner actually wants  to end the process with this command, so other ways of doing that are advised.

One reply that I found had this suggestion, which I thought might work (using an imported C++ 'GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent()'):

```
         Process avrgdb = Process.GetProcessesByName("avr-gdb")[0];
         GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, (uint)avrgdb.SessionId);
```

but it doesn't - apparently the 'SessionId' needs to be that of a  'processGroup' which isn't accessible (or doesn't exist?) in c#, only in C++.

If I knew that rewriting my whole Process interaction in C++ rather than C# would solve this, then I might attempt to do that, but a big learning curve is involved in that approach. Any other ideas please?

Comment: Why the downvote, please? Can I improve my question? If so, how - useful feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution (via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows)); someone has written a C++ application '[SendSignal](http://www.latenighthacking.com/projects/2003/sendSignal/)' . This normally sends  CTRL+Break but I modified the source and recompiled to send CTRL+C.

Starting a third process to control the second from the first seems cumbersome but it works.