# Video Capture, FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a program written in Node.Js that uses the following FFmpeg command to capture video:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video=Integrated Webcam -c:v libx264 -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 60 -segment_format mp4 out%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4
```

There is a need for the video to be interrupted at any time by means of a button. When finalized by the command:

```
taskkill /im ffmpeg.exe /t /f
```

Video is corrupted and can not be played.

Any way to end the process but **preserve** the recorded content?

Comment: You should be able to send it a BREAK signal...maybe :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-segment_format_options movflags=empty_moov`. The files won't be seekable, but you can remux: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy out.mp4`