# simulate ctrl+c event in windows 10 using python

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard-events, pyautogui

I am trying to simulate ctrl+c keyboard event in the python3 using the library pyautogui. Unfortunately, the library doesn't generate this event. Is there any other way to generate this?

The following code is not working,

```
from pyautogui import hotkey

hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
```

I want to do this task for the following code. The code can record live audio for the arbitrary duration and the recording can stop anytime by pressing 'Ctrl+c'. I want to generate this event so that I can add some additional features.

```
import os
import sys
import time
import queue
import soundfile as f
import sounddevice as sd

def callback(indata, frames, time, status):
            """
    This function is called for each audio block from the record function.
    """

    if status:
        print(status, file=sys.stderr)
    q.put(indata.copy())

def record(filename):

    try:
        # Make sure the file is open before recording begins
        with sf.SoundFile(filename, mode='x', samplerate=48000, channels=2, subtype="PCM_16") as file:
            with sd.InputStream(samplerate=48000, channels=2, callback=callback):
                print('START')
                print('#' * 80)
                """ 
                Here is the place I want to generate the event (Ctrl+c) 
                after n minutes
                """
                print('press Ctrl+c to stop the recording')
                while True:
                    file.write(q.get())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('The recording is over.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = queue.Queue()
    record('filename.wav')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion and may not be good, because I'm very beginner in python.

Use [PyWin32](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyWin32) to call windows API `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent()`. You can generate CTRL+C with this API, so it may solve your problem if you call it with `PyWin32`.

**Update:**

Here is my first ever python code. You can use `send_ctrl_c` function to send CTRL-C to another process. I checked it and it works.

```
import win32api as api
import win32console as con

# takes another process id as argument. method sleeps for 2 seconds 
def send_ctrl_c(pid) :
 con.FreeConsole()
 if con.AttachConsole(int(pid)) == None : 
  api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(None, 1)
  api.GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(con.CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)
  api.Sleep(2000)
  con.FreeConsole()
  api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(None, 0)
```

This code is written based on [here](https://codetitans.pl/blog/post/sending-ctrl-c-signal-to-another-application-on-windows) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15281070/5529197).

Comment: In my case it is not working. I will try to explain you clearly. I have a script which records the audio in a live way. The user can stop the recording by pressing Ctrl+c. I want to generate the Ctrl+c for this case so that the user cannot record more n minutes. I edited the question with the code. Please check it.