# Cleanly stopping a multiprocessing.Process - KeyboardInterrupt escapes in Windows

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using multiprocessing to spawn a task ([`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process)) that can be stopped (without cooperation from the task itself, e.g.: without using something like [`multiprocessing.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event) to signal the task to gracefully stop).

Since [`.terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) (or [`.kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.kill)) won't stop it cleanly (the `finally:` clause won't execute), I thought I would use [`os.kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) to emulate a CTRL+C event:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
import os
import signal

def task(n):
    try:
        for i in range(n):
            sleep(1)
            print(f'task: i={i}')
    finally:
        print('task: finally clause executed!')
        return i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Process(target=task, args=(10,))
    print(f'main: starting task...')
    t.start()
    sleep(5)
    for i in ('CTRL_C_EVENT', 'SIGINT'):
        if hasattr(signal, i):
            sig = getattr(signal, i)
            break
    print(f'main: attempt to stop task...')
    os.kill(t.pid, sig)
```

The `finally:` clause executes on both Windows, macOS and Linux; hoever on Windows it additionally spits out the error:

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 357, in
_exit_function
    p.join()
  File "c:\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 149, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "c:\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 108, in wait
    res = _winapi.WaitForSingleObject(int(self._handle), msecs)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

while on macOS and Linux it only print the messages meant to be `print`ed.

Comment: What happens if you make the process `daemon=True`? Note that you then need to keep the main process alive as long as the daemon processes are supposed to run.

Comment: When setting `daemon=True` the same error is printed, and additionally, the `finally:` clause is not executed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems `CTRL_C_EVENT` in Windows is also propagated from the child process to the parent process. See for example [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455684/ctrl-c-event-sent-to-child-process-kills-parent-process).

I added some book keeping code and a `try...except` block to the code. It shows what happens, and that the `KeyboardInterrupt` needs to be caught on parent process as well.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
import os
import signal

def task(n):
    try:
        for i in range(n):
            sleep(1)
            print(f'task: i={i}')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("task: caught KeyboardInterrupt")
    finally:
        print('task: finally clause executed!')
        return i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        t = Process(target=task, args=(10,))
        print(f'main: starting task...')
        t.start()
        sleep(5)
        for i in ('CTRL_C_EVENT', 'SIGINT'):
            if hasattr(signal, i):
                sig = getattr(signal, i)
                break
        print(f'main: attempt to stop task...')
        os.kill(t.pid, sig)

    finally:
        try:
            print("main: finally in main process. Waiting for 3 seconds")
            sleep(3)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("main: caught KeyboardInterrupt in finally block")
```

It prevents the error and produces the following output:

```
main: starting task...
task: i=0
task: i=1
task: i=2
task: i=3
main: attempt to stop task...
main: finally in main process. Waiting for 3 seconds
task: caught KeyboardInterrupt
main: caught KeyboardInterrupt in finally block
task: finally clause executed!
```