# Identifying what triggers a join timeout multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, timeout

I am trying to work out why my multiprocessing hangs, it is not regular, sometimes it will hang after 10 minutes sometimes after hours

This is a reduced version of the code.  I start the job and then join the jobs

```
jobs = []
for item in items_to_do:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=index_a_doc, args=(doc, has_errors))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()

for job in jobs:
    job.join(timeout=20)
    if job.is_alive():
        print("TERMINATED")
    else:
        print("Finished OK.  No Timeout")
```

I added in the join timeout as I was aware that the code hung sometimes.  If it hangs for 20 seconds it terminates.  My question is, am I able to identify where in the code it was before it terminated (where was it hanging) or stop the job that was troublesome and then carry on.

All the jobs are independent of each other, and don't actually need to finish

Thanks

Grant

Comment: You could check out [pystack](https://github.com/bloomberg/pystack) if running on linux. It allows you to inspect the runtime information of the python application, which can be pretty useful for identifying process deadlocks.

Comment: What platform are you running under? Please tag your question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

The exact process will depend on the OS, but I would simulate hitting ctrl-C to cause a keyboard interrupt similar to if I was running a single process and wanted to break it and see where it was. Here's a solution for windows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

from time import sleep

import os
import signal

def worker():
    for i in range(5):
        sleep(1) # stack trace should end here
        print(i+1)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    w = Process(target=worker)
    w.start()

    w.join(2)
    if w.is_alive():
        print("stopping w")
        #w.terminate() #no stack trace is printed with sigterm / windows TerminateProcess
        try: #hack from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455684/ctrl-c-event-sent-to-child-process-kills-parent-process
            os.kill(w.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT) #traceback should be printed on exception
            sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

        w.join()
        print("terminated")
    print("done")
```

Comment: I don't believe Linux defines `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` and unless the code the OP posted is overly reduced, it appears not to be running under Windows.

Comment: Yes, this answer does specifically mention it is for windows, and you would need to choose a different signal on Linux as the two operating systems treat signals differently. There no one signal which works for both identically.