# stop Ctrl + C from propagating upwards

Tags: c++, node.js, windows, winapi, nt

I have a program running (**let's call it A**), and inside this, I'm calling `child_process` from NodeJs to run another application (**let's call it C**). Now I can't change the structure of this, because we already have lots of features implemented in this pattern. So tweaking anything may cause to broken pipeline.

Now I want to terminate that C application, using CTRL+C. As that is a binary, I can't modify the source, so I need to send Ctrl + C to that program. Which I'm doing and it's happily terminating.

Now the issue is, it's killing C **along with A.** So that's the main problem as of now. I've tried creating another intermediate program, as **B**. But then it terminates C, then B, and finally A. So the Ctrl + C is propagating upwards. How can I prevent Ctrl + C from propagating up?

Here goes the pseudo-code:

```
FUNCTION SigintWindows(args):

        INITIALIZE isolate from args
        Create new handle scope with isolate

        GET processId from args[0]

        OPEN process with processId If fails:
            THROW Error("Failed to open process Error code: " + error code)
            EXIT

        TRY attaching to console If fails:
            THROW Error("Failed to attach to console Error code: " + error code)
            TRY sending Ctrl-C event directly If fails:
                THROW Error("Failed to send Ctrl-C event Error code: " + error code)
                CLOSE process handle
                EXIT
            ELSE:
                SET return value to true
                EXIT
        ELSE:
            DISABLE Ctrl-C handling for our program If fails:
                THROW Error("Failed to disable Ctrl-C handling Error code: " + error code)
                CLOSE process handle
                EXIT

            SEND Ctrl-C event If fails:
                THROW Error("Failed to send Ctrl-C event Error code: " + error code)

                RE-ENABLE Ctrl-C handling If fails:
                    THROW Error("Failed to re-enable Ctrl-C handling Error code: " + error code)

                FREE the console
                CLOSE process handle
                EXIT

            ELSE:
                WAIT for the process to exit (max 2 seconds) If process doesn't exit:
                    THROW Error("Process did not exit within 2 seconds")

                RE-ENABLE Ctrl-C handling If fails:
                    THROW Error("Failed to re-enable Ctrl-C handling Error code: " + error code)

                FREE the console
                CLOSE process handle
                EXIT

        END IF

        RE-ENABLE Ctrl-C handling If fails:
            THROW Error("Failed to re-enable Ctrl-C handling")
            CLOSE process handle
            EXIT

        FREE the console
        CLOSE process handle
        SET return value to true
```

And here goes the whole C++ implementation:

```cc
#include <node.h>
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__)
  #include <windows.h>
#endif

namespace ctrlc {

  using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
  using v8::Isolate;
  using v8::Local;
  using v8::Object;
  using v8::String;
  using v8::Value;

  void SigintWindows(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo < v8::Value > & args) {
    #if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__)
      v8::Isolate * isolate = args.GetIsolate();
      v8::HandleScope scope(isolate);

      // Check the number of arguments passed
      if (args.Length() != 1) {
        v8::Local < v8::String > v8String = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Invalid arguments").ToLocalChecked();
        isolate -> ThrowException(v8::Exception::TypeError(v8String));

        return;
      }

      // Check the argument types
      if (!args[0] -> IsUint32()) {
        v8::Local < v8::String > v8String = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Argument must be a number").ToLocalChecked();
        isolate -> ThrowException(v8::Exception::TypeError(v8String));

        return;
      }

      DWORD processId = args[0] -> Uint32Value(isolate -> GetCurrentContext()).ToChecked();

      HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE | PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, processId);
      if (hProcess == NULL) {
        v8::Local<v8::String> v8String = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, ("Failed to open process. Error code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str()).ToLocalChecked();
        isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::Error(v8String));

        return;
      }

      // Try to attach to console
      if (!AttachConsole(processId)) {
        v8::Local<v8::String> v8String = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, ("Failed to attach to console. Error code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str()).ToLocalChecked();
        isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::Error(v8String));

        // If attaching to console fails, try sending Ctrl-C event directly
        if (!GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, processId)) {
          v8::Local<v8::String> v8String = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, ("Failed to send Ctrl-C event. Error code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str()).ToLocalChecked();
          isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::Error(v8String));

          CloseHandle(hProcess);

          return;
        } else {
          args.GetReturnValue().Set(true);
          return;
        }
      } else {
        // Disable Ctrl-C handling for our program
        if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, TRUE)) {
          v8::Local<v8::String> v8String = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, ("Failed to disable Ctrl-C handling. Error code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str()).ToLocalChecked();
          isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::Error(v8String));

          CloseHandle(hProcess);

          return;
        }

        // Send Ctrl-C event
        if (!GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)) {
          v8::Local<v8::String> v8String = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, ("Failed to send Ctrl-C event. Error code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str()).ToLocalChecked();
          isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::Error(v8String));

          // Re-enable Ctrl-C handling
          if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, FALSE)) {
            v8::Local<v8::String> v8String = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, ("Failed to re-enable Ctrl-C handling. Error code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str()).ToLocalChecked();
            isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::Error(v8String));
          }

          FreeConsole();
          CloseHandle(hProcess);
          return;
        } else {
          // Wait for process to exit
          if (WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 2000) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
            v8::Local<v8::String> v8String = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Process did not exit within 2 seconds.").ToLocalChecked();
            isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::Error(v8String));
          }

          // Re-enable Ctrl-C handling
          if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, FALSE)) {
            v8::Local<v8::String> v8String = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, ("Failed to re-enable Ctrl-C handling. Error code: " + std::to_string(GetLastError())).c_str()).ToLocalChecked();
            isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::Error(v8String));
          }

          FreeConsole();
          CloseHandle(hProcess);
          return;
        }
      }

      // Re-enable Ctrl-C handling
      if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL, FALSE)) {
        v8::Local<v8::String> v8String = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Failed to re-enable Ctrl-C handling").ToLocalChecked();
        isolate->ThrowException(v8::Exception::Error(v8String));

        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        
        return;
      }

      FreeConsole();
      CloseHandle(hProcess);
      args.GetReturnValue().Set(True(isolate));
    #endif
  }

  void Init(Local < Object > exports) {
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "sigintWindows", SigintWindows);
  }

  NODE_MODULE(ctrlc, Init)

} // namespace ctrlc
```

**Feel free to provide any solutions or suggestions.**

*NB: I've tried assigning an handler, instead of a none, but that doesn't work either.*

Comment: Caused by AttachConsole(), hard to see why it is necessary.

Comment: It's probably terminating the entire process group. Perhaps if you're child process detaches from that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64840517/6401656

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL+C` signal is sent by the terminal, and is received by all the processes `A` `B` `C` and `D` connected to that terminal at the exact same time.

you should kill the child process `C` by its handle using [TerminateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess), and not by sending a `CTRL+C` event, this way your process `A` is not affected, needless to say this will prevent `C` from doing any resources cleanup, so be careful of that.

another option is to launch `B` and `C` in a separate new terminal, this way `CTRL+C` is sent to the terminal containing only `B` and `C`, therefore `A` will be unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

As [HandlerRoutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine#remarks) said,

> Because the system creates a new thread in the process to execute the
> handler function,...

> Each console process has its own list of HandlerRoutine functions.
> Initially, this list contains only a default handler function that
> calls ExitProcess. A console process adds or removes additional
> handler functions by calling the SetConsoleCtrlHandler function, which
> does not affect the list of handler functions for other processes.

As a general way, you need the target process to execute a specific piece of code which is `ExitProcess` in this case. In the view of `HandlerRoutine`, [@RbMm indicated a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77054281/stop-ctrl-c-from-propagating-upwards#comment135838613_77054281) to call `CreateRemoteThread` in target process with entry point at `CtrlRoutine` and `CTRL_C_EVENT` as parameter.