# Sending data in both directions between Python and lengthy Rust module?

Tags: python, multithreading, rust, signals, pyo3

Pleasantly surprised at the ease of integrating Rust modules into a calling Python app using PyO3.

But the next thing I want to understand is whether it's possible to exchange data between a potentially long-running Rust module and the Python code. A typical case would be where Python is handling the GUI (e.g. PyQt), and a user may want to terminate this long-running Rust-module midstream. So hopefully a graceful interrupt mechanism which the Rust module could detect. "Graceful" would tend to mean not using `SIGINT`, I assume...

But there's also a need for Rust to be able to send out signals in the other direction: a typical case would be a progress indicator to be updated in the GUI. But in another scenario actual significant objects might need to "spun off" from the Rust code and "caught" by the Python code.

Is any of this possible? I can think of an incredibly clunky mechanism: files. If the Python code wants to interrupt, it creates a particular file on disk. The lengthy Rust code is constantly checking to see whether such a file exists, and what the instruction is. Such file mechanism could also be used for data flowing in the other direction.

But I'm hoping there's a better method than this. I've done some searching but not found anything very obvious. An intriguing comment said "Maybe use [crossbeam-channel](https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/latest/crossbeam_channel/) to allow communication between Python and Rust, enabling Python to send a signal/Interrupt to the Rust program?". I had a look at crossbeam-channel, but couldn't see anything addressing this sort of scenario.

Naturally I also looked at PyO3. There doesn't seem to be anything about communication between the respective threads/processes (NB I'm not yet clear whether a called Rust module is in fact running in a different *process* to the calling Python, but I assume so).

***Later***
In fact, according to my experiments, it turns out that, unless you arrange things otherwise, e.g. by using Python `subprocess` or `multiprocessing`, etc., in fact a Rust-to-Python module compiled using `maturin develop` runs **in the same process** as the calling Python code.
The significance of this for this question is that it may be possible to use inter-**thread**-communication, potentially. zeromq, which uses sockets, seems adequate for me to be getting on with (and it is obviously a form of inter-thread communication), and I have no idea how such "superior" within-process inter-thread comms might work. Maybe a suitable expert might have an idea.

It is also intriguing to wonder how the GIL fits into this, when you have a PyO3 (maturin) module running in one thread, and some Python code running in another thread of the same process...

Comment: Does the solution need to be portable? I.e. does it need to run on multiple platforms?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. I'm currently working on W10 but a Linux-only solution would be good to see. Obviously each Rust module is platform-exclusive when built... If you have a solution to this on any platform I'd love to see it!

Comment: I don't see how `SIGINT` isn't graceful. It's catchable and a "polite" way to ask a process to stop. A message bus could be used for passing data between the processes. The first thing that comes to mind is rabbitMQ or some other AMQP implementation. Portability is a nice feature of the message bus option.

Comment: OK fair enough (concerning `SIGINT`). I don't expect you to develop the full details of a possible solution just to answer my question, and I'll try and research those terms tomorrow. Helpful suggestion, thanks. One thing about `SIGINT`: it seems to work significantly differently between W10 and Linux. Which OS do you mainly have in mind?

Comment: I think `SIGINT` is [only available on unix likes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows)

Comment: This all points to a message bus as the preferred communication mechanism. It's portable, behavior is determined by the application rather than the system, the application needs only create/handle the message rather than encode/decode and transport it, and decent message busses provide good fault tolerance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked at a lot of different possibilities.

Best solution seems to be explained [here](https://www.dvlv.co.uk/how-to-do-inter-process-communication-ipc-w-python-and-rust.html), option 3, [zeromq](https://zeromq.org/).

Managed to get simple messages between Python and Rust in minutes (on W10).

I've got a general impression that sockets are slower than pipes. Struggled with various possible solutions, some only for *nix. If anyone can find and give an example of a pipes solution ("named pipes") **for Windows 10**, that'd be great.

**Two important caveats**

1. PyO3 does not appear to be compatible with zmq. When I included the latter dependency in my Cargo.toml and went `maturin develop` this failed. However I have not checked that this is definitely the cause: it may be that another dependency is the problem. Consequently I have put my zmq functionality in another local crate (there is no problem `use`ing this from the PyO3-enabled crate).
2. When running any PyO3 Rust module from Python (in the same process) it appears to be necessary to release the GIL: otherwise Python threads in the Python code will freeze up! See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77083861/595305).