# Erlang installation failed in W10

Tags: visual-c++, windows-10, erlang

Relates to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77054031/595305). I'm trying to set up RabbitMQ on a W10 machine. This apparently involves installing Erlang 64-bit, as Admin.

Downloaded the .exe and tried running as Admin. Fails. The end of the log file is like this:

```
[4398:4A40][2023-09-08T18:36:29]i101: Detected package: vcRuntime_arm64, state: Absent, cached: None
[4398:4A40][2023-09-08T18:36:29]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[4398:4A40][2023-09-08T18:36:29]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[4398:1538][2023-09-08T18:36:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[4398:1538][2023-09-08T18:36:32]e000: Error 0x80070666: Cannot install a product when a newer version is installed.
```

... this error occurred after I got a pop-up dialog saying "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) - 14.29.30139... Setup failed ... Another version of this product is already installed ... ".

I am faintly optimistic that the component which Erlang wants to see is already there but in a later version. There didn't seem to be an option to say "use MS V C++ later version anyway".

Anyone know what I should do?

Comment: Another version of vc++ has been installed in your win 10, To delete it first may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'm reluctant to do that. Because it appears that I have a **newer** version on my system. If I replace that with an older version (as this appears to want to do), mightn't this break something which relies on the newer version?

Answer (score 2):

In the end I just dismissed this MS VC++ dialog and installation just carried on. Eventually installed.