# Maintain responsiveness of PyQt5 and other threads during call to intensive non-Python module?

Tags: python, multithreading, rust, pyqt5, pyo3

This is the first time I've tried writing a Rust module (using PyO3) to be called from Python. OS is W10.

Before, when just using Python, I spent quite a bit of time trying to understand how to maintain responsiveness of PyQt5's "gui thread" (aka "main application thread") when running background threads. I was was originally inspired by this: [How to really, truly use QThreads](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/).

The intensive Rust module is being started from inside such a spawned `QThread`. NB the Rust module is currently executing in the same *process* as the Python app. It is of course possible to run the Rust module in a separate process: then these problems don't occur. But I'm trying to understand why they occur if everything is happening in the same process.

When I run the Python app the first thing is to `show` a very simple `QMainWindow` in the Python, in the main (gui) thread, obviously. I spend the rest of the time wiggling my mouse cursor in front of this.

Next the Rust module is started up from the `QThread`. I'm currently using a threadpool in Rust, and limiting the number of threads to 4. My machine has 8 "logical processors".

Despite using only a maximum of 4 threads in the Rust module, the same thing happens as when I make no attempt to restrict thread use in the Rust module: after about 5 seconds my mouse cursor turns into the dreaded W10 blue spinner, indicating that my app's gui is not responsive. This then lasts to the end of the Rust task, about another 10 seconds.

So I then thought about monitoring thread use in the Python app while all this is happening: I started a simple `threading.Thread` in the Python, which starts before the Rust module starts. This is meant to print out, each second, `threading.active_count()`. But it doesn't. It prints the first value out... and then nothing happens until the Rust module has finished!

So it appears that both the PyQt5 gui thread and also any random additional Python threads are being severely affected by what's happening in the Rust module, even if I limit the threads used in it. Conversely, the blue spinner doesn't appear immediately. It's taking a good 5 seconds or so.

Two other things I tried: restricting the number of threads in the Rust threadpool to 1: same blue spinner. And I also put a few lines like this in the Rust code at a place meaning this would be executed frequently:

```
thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
```

... which is what I need to do in Python to stop non-gui tasks killing the gui responsiveness. Lines like this have no effect.

I'm not at all sure whether this is specific to Rust. I suspect it's probably more a Python question and specifically a PyQt question. Or maybe it's about the mechanisms in PyO3, perhaps? Any insight about these problems or suggestions about where to look for solutions would be helpful.

Comment: [This article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-gil/#bad-scenario-2-long-running-crust-apis-but-author-forgot-to-release-gil) might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go away and experiment with that. The GIL eh? There's a surprise. Ha, and what comes up the first time I search on this: https://pyo3.rs/v0.9.2/parallelism

Comment: Two notes: 1. the article you link is very old and its assumption that overriding `run()` is wrong is, actually, wrong; it can be actually correct to override it (especially in Python), as long as you know what you're doing; 2. the `active_count()` of the python threading module does ***NOT*** return the number of the running threads in the current process, but the number of *Python* `Thread` objects currently alive: if you spawn a thread from Qt, `active_count()` will **not** consider it.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your usual expert input. Can you point me in a direction of an example of what your best practice is for spawning QThreads? I wasn't sure what `active_count` might in fact be counting: I'm not surprised.

Comment: @CarlHR ... amazing. This (`allow_threads`) has cured both problems, i.e. with both Python threads! Blue spinner gone. I'm wondering now what effect (if any) releasing the GIL in the Rust module has on things going on in the Python threads...

Comment: @mikerodent There are fundamentally two ways of using Qt threads: subclassing QThread and overriding `run()`, or moving a QObject to a QThread. In the first case, `run()` normally contains a loop that replaces the thread's event loop, it's simpler and it's usually used for workers that only emit signals (communication *to* the thread can be achieved by executing functions from the caller thread which access objects in the target thread, like basic flags that are periodically checked in the loop or by using queues). The second case allows using bidirectional signals, but only as long as the »

Comment: @mikerodent » functions executed in the thread are not completely blocking: they must periodically (aka, as soon as possible) return control to the thread's event loop so that queued signals can be processed and can eventually call any other function connected to them. There's no absolute best practice, the choice depends on the needs, and each specific situation may be different. For instance, a lazy image loader could take benefit from `moveToThread()` (a signal may "ask" it to process thumbnails). Audio players/recorders probably work better in QThread subclasses since audio is buffered.

Comment: @musicamante Note that when using the 2nd approach, the QThread's event loop will only start running after all connected QObjects (to QThread.started signal) have finished executing. If a QObject is stuck at some intensive operation, they will prevent the event loop from starting, and all incoming signals from the main thread will be ignored. So, though the idea is close to what it should happen, using QObject.moveToThread alone is not enough to achieve bidirectional connection.

Comment: @musicamante I've managed to perform bidirectional signals using the 2nd approach, but it requires a bit of knowledge in the area. You'd have to use the QThread.eventDispatcher() inside the thread scope (after it starts), and register the QObject as a timer, using QAbstractEventDispatcher.registerTimer method. Then, you'd have to use QObject.timerEvent in order to execute code in another thread, allowing you to catch incoming signals from the main thread. I didn't found anything related (articles or doc) and though it was possible to implement, I don't know if its the correct way of doing so.

Comment: @CarlHR About the dispatcher, I actually never realized it (Qt never ceases to amaze me!) and it looks promising; I'll dig more into it, thanks! About your first comment, I see your point, and after checking the sources again you're right: the event loop is actually started within the thread's `exec()`, which is only called *right after* the `started` signal is emitted. It makes perfectly sense: the first thing to do is to "start" whatever needs to be started, then the event loop runs, eventually allowing event (and queued signals) handling. Interestingly enough, it still proves my point: »

Comment: @CarlHR » in the case of a QThread event loop, no connected function should be blocking in order to allow proper signal handling, including whatever happens with `started`: even assuming that the loop was started beforehand, precedence has to be given to what should be *started* first, and any signal should always be handled after it. Btw, if you find any reliable source about the event dispatcher (or you can do further research on your own), I'd suggest you to write a Q&A about it, I'll be more than happy to read about it. Just remember that threads may be handled differently on different OS.

Comment: @musicamante, CarlHR It would also help me if someone could go into and document the necessary forensic detail about this `QThread` stuff. Or maybe there's something already out there. However I just g'd on [qthread "QAbstractEventDispatcher.registerTimer"] and nothing came up.

Comment: @mikerodent As Carl points out, docs about the event dispatcher is practically nonexistent, probably due to its limited niche usage (and even smaller requirement in the Python world, since most of the times the basic usage suffices). I can only suggest you to do some research on your own, also checking the official Qt sources and considering different OS implementations, especially for anything related to their different APIs. Just remember that the GIL always has precedence in some way for Python driven processes, so it may be possible that digging into these aspects may be pointless anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Carl HR put me on the track of [this PyO3 page](https://pyo3.rs/v0.9.2/parallelism) which immediately solved the problem.

> The Python::allow_threads method temporarily releases the GIL, thus
> allowing other Python threads to run.

... or rather both problems: not only is the blue spinner gone, but the `active_count` thread runs unhindered. Incidentally this shows "3" throughout. As mentioned by musicamante in his comment, this is not a particularly helpful indicator.

I assume (until further notice) releasing the GIL like this in the Rust module has no effect on the GIL's behaviour back in the Python code.

Naturally this is just the start of the journey. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/mj6h08/comment/gt8n1e8/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), for example, suggests that using Python objects in such Rust code can effectively cancel the effect of `allow_threads`. I have not yet experimented to put this assertion to the test.