# How to take Heap dump after the stack overflow error in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting the stack overflow error. How to take heap dump and know the reason?

Comment: you are getting a `stack` overflow, and you want a `heap` dump?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018675/making-a-memory-dump-of-java-application

Comment: Is this VM argument (-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError) works in case of stack overflow error too?

Comment: Yes @Eugene. For OutOfMemoryError we can use -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError in VM argument but in case of stack overflow error how  to take heap dump?

Comment: A heapdump is not going to help you. What you want is a stacktrace, which you probably already have, unless there's some exception handling interfering.