# keyStore.load(null,null) hangs

Tags: java, smartcard

I was trying load `keystore` from `smartCard`. I have a valid `smartcard` with self signed cert.

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY")
keyStore.load(null,null);
```

It hangs up on `KeyStore.loadKeysorCertificateChains(String,Collection<KeyEntry>)` with no response back. I am wondering what the problem could be.

Should I add root cert into `CERT` keys or am I missing something else?

Comment: Take a thread dump to reveal what it happening under the hood: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407612/how-to-get-a-heap-dump-of-a-java-process-on-windows-thats-not-running-in-a-cons