# jmeter stops sending soap requests

Tags: jmeter

We are load testing some java soap service and have launched jmeter test suite of ~ 300 threads by 3000 similar requests. Each request is approximately 250kbytes of data (due to base64 entry), and after sending 7 hundred something (successful) requests jmeter has simply stopped sending any. Test suite still 'runs' (stop button is available) but no requests are sent, it just does nothing.

Another similar test suite, with the same number of smaller requests (3-4 KB) runs about 20K requests and then the very same thing happens: test suite 'runs' but nothing at all happens.

Question is: what are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using GUI to test, this is against Best-Practices:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean
- http://www.dzone.com/links/see_how_to_make_jmeter_run_thousands_of_threads_w.html

If you are also using a View Results tree in this test, then you are facing OutOfMemory issues.

> Don't use "View Results Tree" or "View Results in Table" listeners during the load test, use them only during scripting phase to debug your scripts.

Running test in non-gui will fix your issue, if you still want to run in GUI mode disable View Results tree.

Answer (score 0):

Do a Threaddump of your running JMeter Application when you think it is stuck. (Howto: [How to get a thread and heap dump of a Java process on Windows that's not running in a console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407612/2003273)).

In the Threaddump you need to find your threadgroups. The name of such thread is something like "Thread [Thread Group 1-12]".

Examine what the threads are doing/if they are waiting.