# Analyze Heap usage in Java 8 Release 144 - feature removed? how to analyze heap then?

Tags: server, java-8, heap-memory, heap-dump

I am trying to use the heap and jstat commands to analyze heap usage by the different IDE and programs using Java, as my machine is incredibly slow.

I have 16 GIG Ram, my min Heap is 252MB, my max Heap is 3,9 Gig. Now I want to know the heap usage by different programs.

jmap was experimental and removed in Release 60, can you kindly tell me if there is

1) a way to use jmap in Release 144 using Java Advanced Management Console? If so, how?

2) An alternative program / command line manager by a third party to analyze Java heap usage?

3) Would Java Usage Tracker be an alternative? If so, what would I need to consider?

Thank you.

BR,
SN

Answer (score 0):

You can do a thread dump in linux - `kill -3 [java-process-number]`,
the thread dump will appear in the log file of the process.
In the end of the thread dump you will see some statistic about the heap usage.
example:

```
Heap
 garbage-first heap   total 524288K, used 14336K [0x00000007a0000000, 0x00000007a0101000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 15 young (15360K), 0 survivors (0K)
 Metaspace       used 8584K, capacity 8688K, committed 8832K, reserved 1056768K
 class space    used 1022K, capacity 1080K, committed 1152K, reserved 1048576K
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407612/how-to-get-a-thread-and-heap-dump-of-a-java-process-on-windows-thats-not-runnin