# How to fine tune JVM configurations to reduce the max thread stack size?

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, jvm, jvm-arguments

I want to change the default thread stack size in Java for my Spring-Boot Web application. How can I change this? or which parameter I need to use to change this value?

Also, the second question is, can I programmatically change this at runtime?

Comment: May be you can look into this, which is a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407612/how-to-get-a-thread-and-heap-dump-of-a-java-process-on-windows-thats-not-runnin

Comment: Hi @AshutoshChamoli, thanks for the help, let me look into this, it may help.

Comment: the real question is why you would want to do that, stacks are filled lazy

Comment: Hey @Eugene, what do you mean by `stacks are filled lazy`, can you please explain or share any documentation. Also, in case, I want threads of smaller stack size, just to increase the number of parallel threads my server can handle, what shall I do?

Comment: @ZestBest not exactly documentation, but this article of mine contains some experiments illustrating lazy stack filling with Docker memory limits - https://bell-sw.com/announcements/2020/10/28/JVM-in-Linux-containers-surviving-the-isolation/

Comment: @AlexeyRagozin you are part of bellsoft too?? That is one dream team right there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Basically, you can configure the max Stack size of your thread in your application.

For this, you can use the option named `ss` to adjust the maximum stack size. A VM option is usually passed using `-X{option}`. So you can use `java -Xss1M` to set the maximum of stack size to `1M`.

One more example is `java -Xss1048576`, this sets the max thread size to approximately 1 MB

Checkout the two below blogs also for more info and other flags.

-> https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-configure-stack-sizes

-> https://docs.gigaspaces.com/latest/production/production-jvm-tuning.html

Answer (score 2):

I want to add a couple of very useful resources:

- [Java using much more memory than heap size (or size correctly Docker memory limit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438)

> The default is 1M per thread, but fortunately the things are not so bad. OS allocates memory pages lazily, i.e. on the first use, so the actual memory usage will be much lower (typically 80-200 KB per thread stack).

- https://pangin.pro/posts/stack-overflow-handling

> in JDK 11/12 [minimum thread stack size] is: min_stack_size = 40 KB + (1 + 2 + 1 + 20) * 4 KB = 136 KB
>
> If I try to set a lower value, I’ll expectedly get an error:
>
> /usr/java/jdk-12.0.2/bin/java -Xss100k
>
> The Java thread stack size specified is too small. Specify at least 136k

Comment: @ZestBest I think the first one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438) also answers your question regarding "stacks are filled lazy,"